# AppKey cannot be null or empty

Tags: android, e-commerce

I am trying to develope an android ecommerce UI for demo. I downloaded the template files from this source at github https://github.com/Appdynamics/ECommerce-Android. When I run the application in android studio everything builds fine but when I go to open the app on my emulator it crashes with this error message in the logcat

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.appdynamics.demo.android.CustomApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppKey cannot be null or empty
```

I think the problem is coming from this line of code by I'm not sure how to fix it

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {


@Override
@InfoPoint
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    setGlobalData();
    Instrumentation.start(GlobalDataProvider.getInstance().getEumAppKey(),
            getApplicationContext(),
            GlobalDataProvider.getInstance().getCollectorUrl(),
            true);
```

Here is the preferences.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"       android:title="@string/action_settings">
<EditTextPreference android:key="pref_rest_uri"    android:title="@string/pref_rest_uri"
/><!-- android:defaultValue="http://192.168.31.117:8000/appdynamicspilot/"-->pref_eum_eum_app_key
<EditTextPreference android:key="pref_eum_app_key" android:title="@string/pref_eum_app_key"/>
<EditTextPreference android:title="@string/pref_eum_collector_url" android:key="pref_eum_collector_url"/>


</PreferenceScreen>
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error as you have not provided the  values required by app to work. You need to add the values in `PreferenceConstants` .

```
public final class PreferenceConstants {
    public final static String END_POINT_URL = ""; //Put appropriate value here
    public static final String EUM_APP_KEY = ""; //Put appropriate value here
    public static final String EUM_COLLECTOR_URL = ""; //Put desired value here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, do I have to create this file or is it all ready created?

Comment: Sorry to ask such simple questions I am very new to app development. Does it matter what I put inside these strings?

Comment: Yes of course. All the values should be valid. I don't know much about this project , so you have to find it yourself, what are these for ?

Comment: Yes what are these PreferenceConstants for? Also I found preferences.xml that have values in them but i'm not sure what to do with them

Comment: Set the server urls and app key in PreferenceConstants.java . These are used throughout the app and without that the app won't work.

Comment: And Prefs xml is used for editing the same values from UI . In case you want to change it from the app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108438/discussion-between-brian-smith-and-shadab-ansari).

Answer (score 0):

Did you get it working? Actually, you know. You are trying to connect to server and app key is the one generated at server and has to be implemented at end application. Since this is a template, there is no server allocated by the code writer to test and so you don't have app key. Try exploring IoT frameworks by IBM any other or even you can try open source, Kaa. It will be worth if want explore this kind of cloud dependent apps.